# Elasticsearch: Node registered to cluster but MasterNotDiscoveredException

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot

I´m having a variation of the usual connection problem between ElasticSearch nodes, however here it does not seem to be related to the network as the client registers with the master without any problem (apparently). My set-up is the following:

One Master node (`node.master=true`, `node.data=true`, `cluster.name=stokker`)

One Client node (Spring Boot 1.3.0.M5) with these settings:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.http.enabled=true
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=stokker
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.node.local=false
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.node.data=false
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.node.client=true
```

First I start the master node, then the client and I can see that the client registers OK:

```
[Kilmer] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[Kilmer] watch service has started
[Kilmer] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9201]}, publish_address         {inet[/159.107.28.230:9201]}
[Kilmer] started
[Kilmer] added {[Thunderclap][VVF_5QnLREac-Du-dZK1IQ][ES00052260][inet[/159.107.28.230:9301]]{client=true, data=false, local=false},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(join from node[[Thunderclap][VVF_5QnLREac-Du-dZK1IQ]    [ES00052260][inet[/159.107.28.230:9301]]{client
```

Client´s console output

```
org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Thunderclap] version[1.7.0], pid[12084], build[929b973/2015-07-16T14:31:07Z]
org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Thunderclap] initializing ...
org.elasticsearch.plugins                : [Thunderclap] loaded [], sites []
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap              : JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Thunderclap] initialized
org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Thunderclap] starting ...
org.elasticsearch.transport              : [Thunderclap] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9301]}, publish_address {inet[/159.107.28.230:9301]}
org.elasticsearch.discovery              : [Thunderclap] stokker/VVF_5QnLREac-Du-dZK1IQ
org.elasticsearch.discovery              : [Thunderclap] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
org.elasticsearch.http                   : [Thunderclap] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9202]}, publish_address {inet[/159.107.28.230:9202]}
org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Thunderclap] started
```

However, when I try to perform some indexing, I get the following exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
```

Any ideas on what am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: From the logs you provided, I'm not seeing anything that indicates any of the nodes are master.

Comment: Node.master is set to true in one of the nodes. Do I need any other parameter in order to have a master? Thanks!

Comment: No, I'm saying that you haven't posted relevant enough logs so that I can establish anything useful about the issue.

Comment: That´s all the logging I get from both the server and client. I´ll try to set the logging level to TRACE to see if I can get something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding this property manually indicating where the master node is:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=192.168.1.18:9300
```

If somebody finds a better solution, please let me know, I´m not fully confident in this one.